# failed to configure C/C++ 'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to upgradle gradle version to 8.1 .I am using agp 8.1.1 and target and compile sdk 34 and build tool version is also 34 minsdk version is 21 I have installed android sdk 14 but I am still getting this error failed to configure build c/c++ I dont know the root cause of it these are the logs

```
:libs:encutil debug:x86 failed to configure C/C++
'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)'
    at com.android.repository.util.InstallerUtil.unzip(InstallerUtil.java:99)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doPrepare(BasicInstaller.java:91)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:340)
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installRemotePackages(DefaultSdkLoader.java:365)
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installSdkTool(DefaultSdkLoader.java:454)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.installCMake(SdkHandler.java:343)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkComponentsBuildService.installCmake(SdkComponents.kt:388)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.NativeLocationsBuildService$locateCMake$1$1$2.accept(NativeLocationsBuildService.kt:78)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.NativeLocationsBuildService$locateCMake$1$1$2.accept(NativeLocationsBuildService.kt:72)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.CmakeLocatorKt.findCmakePathLogic(CmakeLocator.kt:424)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.CmakeLocator.findCmakePath(CmakeLocator.kt:475)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.NativeLocationsBuildService$locateCMake$1$1.apply(NativeLocationsBuildService.kt:72)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.NativeLocationsBuildService$locateCMake$1$1.apply(NativeLocationsBuildService.kt:69)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.NativeLocationsBuildService.locateCMake(NativeLocationsBuildService.kt:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.NativeLocationsBuildServiceKt.rewriteWithLocations(NativeLocationsBuildService.kt:179)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.v2.NativeModelBuilder$createGenerator$1.apply(NativeModelBuilder.kt:91)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.v2.NativeModelBuilder$createGenerator$1.apply(NativeModelBuilder.kt:84)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.v2.NativeModelBuilder.createGenerator(NativeModelBuilder.kt:84)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.v2.NativeModelBuilder.generateBuildFilesAndCompileCommandsJson(NativeModelBuilder.kt:207)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.v2.NativeModelBuilder.buildAll(NativeModelBuilder.kt:172)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.v2.NativeModelBuilder.buildAll(NativeModelBuilder.kt:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuilderWithParameter.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:289)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$UserCodeAssigningBuilder.lambda$build$0(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:374)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$UserCodeAssigningBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:374)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$LockSingleProjectBuilder.lambda$build$0(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:304)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$2(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:418)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:418)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$LockSingleProjectBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:304)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder$1.call(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:337)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:334)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController$AbstractToolingScope.getModel(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:85)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:108)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:97)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncActionRunnerKt$toMeasuringController$1$findModel$4.invoke(SyncActionRunner.kt:286)
    at com.android.tools.idea.projectsystem.gradle.sync.Counter.invoke(PerformanceMeasurementUtil.kt:108)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncActionRunnerKt.measure(SyncActionRunner.kt:327)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncActionRunnerKt.access$measure(SyncActionRunner.kt:1)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncActionRunnerKt$toMeasuringController$1.findModel(SyncActionRunner.kt:286)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ActionToRun$toSafeController$1.findModel(SyncActionRunner.kt:160)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ModelFetchersKt.findNativeVariantAbiModel(ModelFetchers.kt:139)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncProjectActionWorker$getVariantAction$1$1.invoke(SyncProjectActionWorker.kt:355)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncProjectActionWorker$getVariantAction$1$1.invoke(SyncProjectActionWorker.kt:344)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ModelResult$Companion.create(ModelResult.kt:32)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncProjectActionWorker$getVariantAction$1.invoke(SyncProjectActionWorker.kt:344)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncProjectActionWorker$getVariantAction$1.invoke(SyncProjectActionWorker.kt:343)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ActionToRun$map$1.invoke(SyncActionRunner.kt:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ActionToRun$map$1.invoke(SyncActionRunner.kt:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ActionToRun.run$intellij_android_projectSystem_gradle_sync(SyncActionRunner.kt:77)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncActionRunner$runActions$executionResults$1$1.execute(SyncActionRunner.kt:231)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter$1.get(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController$NestedAction.run(DefaultBuildController.java:208)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.runQueryModelActions(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:97)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.run(DefaultBuildController.java:129)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.run(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:55)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction$MyBuildController.run(ProjectImportAction.java:731)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncActionRunner.runActions(SyncActionRunner.kt:229)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncProjectActionWorker.chooseSelectedVariants(SyncProjectActionWorker.kt:246)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncProjectActionWorker.access$chooseSelectedVariants(SyncProjectActionWorker.kt:27)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncProjectActionWorker$populateAndroidModels$2.invoke(SyncProjectActionWorker.kt:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncProjectActionWorker$populateAndroidModels$2.invoke(SyncProjectActionWorker.kt:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.projectsystem.gradle.sync.Counter.invoke(PerformanceMeasurementUtil.kt:108)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncProjectActionWorker.populateAndroidModels(SyncProjectActionWorker.kt:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:99)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderImpl.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:113)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProvider.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:427)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:73)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)


'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)'
```

I don't know what is the real reason ? can anyone help?